# Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr, any clue?

Tags: errors, cases

Anyone know what could be causing the problem here?

```
$$h(s) =

\begin{cases}

(a,0)\ & \text{if } a \not\in S\ &

(a,1)\ & \text{if } a \in S

\end{cases}

$$
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, report the code exactly as you have it in your source.

Comment: did you cut and paste this code from an earlier question on this site?  it looks suspiciously like an example of the problem reported [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7168/579).  if so, please let us know where you found it, so that the original can be corrected.

Comment: @barbara No, this is from one of my own proofs for a problem in Aluffi's Abstract Algebra textbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have one `&` too many and one `\\` too few.

You don't have any blank lines in the math material either, do you?

As egreg pointed out, with `mathtools` package there's `cases*`, where the second column is in text mode by default.

Moreover see also [Why is [ … ] preferable to $$ … $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
h(s) =
\begin{cases}
(a,0) & \text{if $a\notin S$} \\
(a,1) & \text{if $a \in S$}
\end{cases}
\]
or 
\[
h(s) =
\begin{cases*}
(a,0) & if $a\notin S$ \\
(a,1) & if $a \in S$
\end{cases*}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of making your write-up a bit more idiomatic (English). Feel free to revert.

Comment: @Mico Thank you, I was editing simultenously also to add http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: It's easier to type `\text{if $a\notin S$}`; with `mathtools` there's `cases*` where the second column is in text mode by default. Note `\notin` rather than `\not\in`.